# getParcelable() returns null object

Tags: android

I've used `putExtra()` to pass some data from one activity to other. I want to create a `Parcelable` instance but I am getting a null object.

Here is the code of first activity:

```
i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra(com.login_app.Activity1.extra, "100");
startActivity(i);
```

Here is the code of second activity:

```
Intent inew = getIntent();
Bundle icicle1 = inew.getExtras();
// this is just a debug code
System.out.println(
    icicle1.getSerializable(com.login_app.Activity1.extra).toString());
Parcelable p = inew.getParcelableExtra(com.login_app.Activity1.extra);
```

Here object p is a null object.

Please tell me if I am wrong or I need to add something else. I want this Parcelable object to be flattened into a Parcel object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you've put `String`, but trying to get `Parcelable`. You should use `getStringExtra` instead.

Also, from `Bundle` documentation of `[getParcelable()][1]` (this function is used to actually get extra from `Intent`'s bundle):

> Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key or a null value is explicitly associated with the key.

So you basically get `null` because you have type mismatch.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a Parcelable object to be flattened in Parcel?

Comment: That is a separate question. Please use the search function on [so] and post a new question if there is no answer to your question.